# Unity freezes when I try to check, asynchrounsly, an username from firebase firestore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, mobile-application

Hi I'm building the sign up scene for my application, but when it's to check if an username exists the entire unity freezes.

so here's all the functions i've tried:

this is the one from firebase docs

```
       public async Task<bool> checkIfExists(string WhatToCheck="username", string TextToCheck) {
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
            CollectionReference docRef = db.Collection("users");
            Query query = docRef.WhereEqualTo(WhatToCheck, TextToCheck);
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
            foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in querySnapshot.Documents) {
                return true;
            }


            return false;

        }
```

Then i've tried

```
       public async Task<bool> checkIfExists(string WhatToCheck, string TextToCheck) {
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
            var docRef = db.Collection("users");
            Query docQuery=docRef.WhereEqualTo(WhatToCheck,TextToCheck);

            List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot = new List<DocumentSnapshot>((await docQuery.GetSnapshotAsync()).Documents);
     
            foreach(DocumentSnapshot snap in snapshot) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }
```

I've even tried this:

```
           FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
           var docUser = db.Collection("users");
           Query docRef = docUser.WhereEqualTo(WhatToCheck, TextToCheck);

           docRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
               QuerySnapshot booksQuerySnapshot = task.Result;

               foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in booksQuerySnapshot.Documents) {

                   return true;


               }
               return false;
           });
           return false;
```

the last works, but, for obvius reasons, it always return false

this is my users collection in firebase:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxZC6.png

---

Edit: just found out the problem is this function that I use to convert Task to bool

```
public bool checkIfExistsUsernameConverter(string TextToCheck) {
    return checkIfExists(TextToCheck).Result; 
}
```

this is what freezes the application;

---

Edit: I solved the freezing problem. The problem was that I didn't put an awaiter in the function reference:

```
  bool UsernameExists = await Task.Run(() => Database.current.checkIfExistsUsernameConverter(usernameIF.text));
```

but now it gives me this error with no line code reference:

> ArgumentException: method return type is incompatible
> System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure, System.Boolean allowClosed) (at :0)

Comment: So is the issue that it freezes or that it returns false? Note that the outer `return` is already done long before your async snapshot was actually received ... Also your inner return within the lambda expression only returns from that lambda expression .. not your method.

Comment: The issue is that it freezes, except for the last method that return false everytime for the reason that you said

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not support - I repeat - not support `async/await`.
The reason is, that Unity3D is an application written in C++ and you just interact with it via interop and they use their very own multithreading environment. You could theoretically create and manage your own threads "the old way", but that would cause context switches, because of their system.
To use multithreading in Unity, you need to use the JobSystem https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html

Comment: It's not the first time I use async/await in unity,  it works everytime except for this case

Comment: ..Until you build your game :) 
Point is, officially, Unity does not even attempt to fix anything related to async/await in their own, custom Mono runtime - meaning it's not supported. It is not only even less performant than using synchronous code, it is bad practice and not the Unity standard. Also, the JobSystem is really well made. Remember: Async/await is not thread-safe; The JobSystem is. But hey, it's your choice :D